# Invalid image type when using Apple music

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

The artwork shows when selecting music from a playlist, but throws an error:

> "Invalid image type at musicview.js"

if selecting a song outside of the playlist. How can have it fail without throwing an error.

```
    if (player.nowPlaying.artwork) {
        $.iv.image = player.nowPlaying.artwork;
    }
```

Comment: This is the error code:                                                                                      `[INFO] :   {
[INFO] :       column = 17;
[INFO] :       line = 267;
[INFO] :       message = "invalid image type";
[INFO] :       nativeLocation = "-[TiUIImageView setImage_:] (TiUIImageView.m:715)";
[INFO] :       nativeReason = "expected TiBlob, String, TiFile, was: TiBlob";
[INFO] :       stack = "";
[INFO] :   }`

Comment: Not sure, but maybe you can use a try catch on it, like:

```try {
         $.iv.image = player.nowPlaying.artwork;
      } catch (exception) {
         console.log('error');
      }```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. That's what I did to obtain to obtain the error code above. With the try and catch, it allows the app to keep working. The music plays, the titles show, but the image does not.